# Vertically center text on line with inline graphic in Scribus

Tags: typesetting, scribus, mathematics

I would like to embed a picture inside a text frame in Scribus, I think Scribus calls them inline graphics.

Unfortunately, the picture exceeds the height of the line, so Scribus increases the spacing to the previous line. I want Scribus to increase the spacing only by half of the needed height, getting the remaining space from the next line, just like LaTeX does. In LaTeX, the text is in the center of the line, in Scribus the text is on the bottom.

A picture says more than a thousand words.

This is what I have:
[image: Scribus]

This is what I want:
[image: LaTeX]

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the inline graphic by highlighting it, right click it, and choose Properties

Click the Text tab, then Advanced Settings tab, then change the Baseline Offset setting to a negative value.

[image]

Comment: correct! just one remark: you need at least scribus 1.4.7 ( the latest stable release at the time of writing), since this was behavior was buggy in 1.4.6 ... but it's not a good idea to use outdated software anyway : - )